# upload document file in stripe payment with React

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

According to the  [Stripe API for verification document in front](https://stripe.com/docs/api/persons/create#create_person-verification-document-front) I can see that creating a file in Javascript isn't available, and I want to create a file verification ID on the client side using React/Javascript.

I successfully created a bank account but when I try to upload an identity verification file through my React client interface with method `stripe.files.create` does not work and returns `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` knowing that `stripe.createToken` works so stripe is well integrated into my application.

Note that I interact with stripe from client side developed with React.

```js
  stripeVerification = async () => {
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', this.state.picture[0], 'picture');
    await this.props.stripe.files
      .create({
        purpose: 'identity_document',
        file: {
          data: formdata,
        },
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a file client-side using the approach documented in [the "Handling a file upload" section of Stripe's Connect documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#file-upload).

> When a user needs to provide Stripe with a [scan of an identity document](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#handling-identity-verification) (for example, a passport), you can also do this through an account token. However, the JavaScript required is a bit more complicated as the file must be sent to Stripe as part of an XHR request.

Comment: According to this doc https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens we can do it from client-side

Comment: You're correct, my fault!  I've corrected the answer based on your comment.